# Removing data from MYSQL that is comma delimited via Get and php

Tags: php, mysql

What I am doing is adding values to a mysql table with each value seperated by a comma. And each new value is appended to that last value once again seperated by a comma. Now this is all dynamic. What I am having an issue is on how to remove a selected value and the comma. I am using php and mysql. 
I can read the values out with explode and line[value].

table name is values

table consist of id, value, value_array

$value_selected would be a $_GET['value']

value_array is the column that contains all the values seperated by comma.

The database selects from values where the id is equal to the Get value.
Then returns all values in the value_array

I then explode the values and have each value from the value_array read through the for loop and line[value].

```
the code:
start php
$value_selected = $_GET['value'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values WHERE id='$value_selected'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$check_values = $result['value_array'];
} 

$values = explode(",",$check_values);
$count_values = count($values);

for($counter = 0; $counter < $count_values; $counter++)
{
$line = each($values);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM values WHERE id='$line[value]'");
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $result['value'].'<br/>'; 
}
}
php end
```

I don't have an issue reading it out. What I'm trying to do is being able to select a value via GET and remove that value from the value_array while also removing the trailing comma. I hope I was able to expalin in more detail my issue.

Comment: " adding values to a mysql table with each value seperated by a comma" that's the problem, your need to understand db normalisation

Comment: Actually it's not a problem. It's done all the time. The problem is preg_match the data I need removing that data and the trailing comma. I've done many db's like this. This is the first time I've had to remove a selected value whether at the front or middle or the last.

Comment: done all the time by people who dont know how to do it poerperly

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop, take the exploded string and reassemble it minus the string $value_selected by doing this:

```
$NewValue = '';
$i = 1;
foreach ($values as $Value) {
    if ($i > $count_values) {
        break;
    } else {
        if ($Value !== $value_selected) {//reassemble comma-sep string - $_GET['value']
            $NewValue = $NewValue . $Value . ",";
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Now $NewValue no longer contains $_GET['value'], because the concatenation in the if statement only occurs when the exploded fragment $Value does not match $_GET['value']. Update the database or echo $NewValue, etc. as necessary at this point.